# Is hair part of the human body or not?

Tags: halacha-theory, hair, lomdus, head, boneh-soter

Inspired by [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17518/5), I'm curious. We hold that hair of a married woman is 'Ervah (ערוה).  Yet it is not 'Ervah for an unmarried woman.  According to the [Gemara in Shabbath (Bab. 95a)](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=shabbos&daf=95a&go=Go), braiding the hair is "building".

Now, [ממה נפשך](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2304/5323) -- if it is part of the human body, why is braiding it "building"?

If it is not part of the human body, how can it be 'Ervah?

Comment: Who said building cannot be done with body parts??

Comment: @DovF, really??? It just makes no sense. If I spill scalding hot molten pig fat on my hand, does that mean I can't suck my thumb?

Comment: Why can't something that isn't a part of your body be erva?

Comment: @SethJ Your thumb is cold.

Comment: @DovF, and if I accidentally pour scalding cow's milk on my hand later that same day, am I prohibited from licking the burn to soothe it (I'm making this ben yomo even though in shear isurim we say even eino ben yomo is asur)? And yes, I know, I'd probably better off staying out of the kitchen for a while.

Comment: @SethJ I don't understand the value of these rhetorical questions. You haven't provided any support or basis for your premise that no halachic building can be done with the human body. It is obviously an incorrect premise since hair is halachicly part of the body, as I've shown. Therefore as far as I'm concerned that is the only correct premise, ואידך פירושא, זיל גמור.

Comment: @SethJ Whether or not your body accepts taste seems to have absolutely nothing to do with if you can build with it l'inyan shabbat. I don't see any reason to assume Melachot can't be done with the body (Gozez and Dash come to mind) nor any reason why being a part of the body is a prerequisite for erva status (consider a Niddah's colorful clothes or a Playboy magazine). Additionally, we might consider hair part of the body for some things (Mikva) but not others (Kevura).

Comment: Voice is also not part of the body, yet קול באשה ערוה.

Comment: ...Plus, _chay eno bolea_.

Comment: Consider this the grumbling of the downvoted OP, and therefore take it with a grain of salt, but is this question so unworthy as to deserve -3, or is it because of my strong tone (intended to draw attention)? @DovF et al.

Comment: @SethJ, the former, I think (though I didn't vote on it, myself).

Comment: @SethJ I'm skeptical of the question's premise, but I didn't downvote... yet (bwahahaha). I think you should provide some source that suggests that 1.) *ervah* generally only applies to body parts (which I doubt in part because of קול באשה ערוה (Berachos 24a)), and 2.) *boneh* cannot be effected with the body (which I doubt because of the last Rashi on Kesuvos 6b (s.v. *Chayyav*)).

Comment: @SethJ For the record I didn't downvote.

Comment: @SethJ I haven't voted on the question.

Comment: So nobody who has commented has voted. Interesting, but shocking.

Answer (score 5):

To answer a mistaken premise of the question -- *boneh* is possible on the human body.

See [Shabbos 107a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=107&format=pdf):

> המפיס מורסא בשבת אם לעשות לה פה חייב אם להוציא ממנה לחה פטור
>
> If someone pops a pimple on Shabbos -- if he did so to make an
>   opening, then he is liable for punishment; if he intended to remove
>   the pus from inside, he is not liable

Rashi there says:

> חייב. משום בונה פתח או משום מתקן כלי מה לי לתקן מכה מה לי לתקן כלי
>
> He is liable: because of *boneh* or because of *metaken kli*
>   (fixing/creating a vessel); what does it matter if he fixed a *kli* or
>   a wound? (both are fixing things, and are therefore forbidden)

So we see that *boneh* is possible on the human body, and thus the fact that *boneh* is possible doesn't detract at all from hair being a body-part.

(*all translations mine*)

Comment: I thought Rashi there explained that "making an opening" meant להכניס ולהוציא, but I might be thinking of a Rashi on a different gemara where מפיס מורסא came up. If you could help me out with that, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Hair is part of the body. The Gemara ([Sukkah 6a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=6&format=pdf)) calls it טפל לבשרו; secondary to the flesh, but clearly a legitimate part of the body, as it needs to be included in *tevila* (ibid).

As to why @SethJ heard that a married woman's hair is ervah and not an unmarried woman's, the source that hair is ervah is Berachos 24a. The Mordechai there cites a Ra'avya (an opinion echoed by various rishonim) that things which in any particular society people are used to, do not retain the status of ervah, despite the Gemara naming them so. So it's really a case of the chicken and the egg; the single women do not uncover their hair because it isn't ervah; rather it isn't ervah because they uncover their hair.

I fail to see how any of this would have bearing on Hilchos Shabbos.

Comment: How can you effect Boneh with a part of your body?

Comment: @SethJ Why not? What is the basis of your premise that you cannot? I don't think it needs to be said that the "building" we are talking about is more a legal term than simply one you can find defined in Webster's dictionary.

Comment: No, it has to be something that was found in Binyan HaMishkan. Which is to say, building as we know it, and virtually identical to Webster's definition of same.

Comment: Come on. They didn't build with electric drills in the mishkan either, yet we apply the principle of 'building' to building with an electric drill, because there is no *halachicly significant* difference. You have not shown that there is a halachicly significant difference between building with sticks and stones and building with body parts. You've merely made a rhetorical remark.

Comment: It's not a rhetorical remark. The Gemara deals with definitions of what happened in the construction of the Mishkan. Look at Daf 94/95. Why is carrying a person ok? Because it wasn't part of the construction of the Mishkan.

Comment: Again, it's because there are *halachicly significant* differences. In the case of carrying the person, it's because of the principle that a person carries his own weight; חי נושא את עצמו. Simply that it seems so different doesn't carry much weight.

Comment: I see what you did there...

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Mishna Berurah siman 303 #82 the reason braiding hair would be Boneh rather than Oreig is specifically because it is attached to and part of the human body. This then would not be a contradiction to the fact that it is an erva, but rather a complimentary idea.

Comment: The *Mishna B'rura* implies that one reason why a person would not be biblically liable for braiding attached hair is that the braiding is meant to be temporary, whereas someone weaving disconnected hairs together would be liable if they are weaving something that is meant to be lasting. So the fact that it is connected to the head has no intrinsic impact on whether a person is biblically liable for braiding (except that the violation is *boneh* with attached hair but it is *oreig* with disconnected hair).

Comment: @Fred I'm not sure what you mean to say. The op was wondering concerning hair if boneh and erva are a stira. I quoted the point from the M.B. which shows this assumption is incorrect and the only reason to even discuss if it is related to boneh at all is because it is connected to the body, not in spite of that fact. The details of what the M.B. actual point was is not what I wanted to bring out. I was focusing only on the boneh aspect.

Comment: I see. I was confused since I read your phrasing as implying that attachment to the body makes *boneh d'oraisa* intrinsically inapplicable. Perhaps consider rephrasing "*one of the reasons braiding hair is not* Boneh *on a* deoraisa *level is specifically because it is attached*" to "*the reason braiding hair is* Boneh *rather than* Oreig *is specifically because it is attached*".