# Is hair considered as flesh for tachanun (nefilat apaim)?

Tags: halacha, hair, tachanun

From the answer to [Is a cloth covering required for Tachanun?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40628/is-a-cloth-covering-required-for-tachanun):

> The Aruch Hashulchan (131:7) and Mishnah Berurah (131:3) both say that one should cover his face with a cloth and not merely one's hand, because a person's own flesh can't be considering a covering for itself.

What about hair? **Is hair considered an acceptable covering for this, or is it still part of the body?** Assuming your own hair, attached to your head.

In case anyone is wondering how this would even work... i need a haircut.

Also see [Putting the head down for Tachanun with a non-cloth covering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/putting-the-head-down-for-tachanun-with-a-non-cloth-covering)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25677

Comment: Hair must get dunked in the Mikva. In what case is hair considered separate?