# Braiding hair on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat

I am looking for a source that provides a clear halachic (non-aggadic) and rational explanation on why the Gemara (Shabbat 95a) prohibits braiding hair as a kind of building.  [This similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17513/3483) asks and receives answers to this question using aggadic concepts and methods, but I am asking if there is a rationale for this prohibition that is based purely on halachic reasoning.

Although the gemara sources itself in the word ויבן from the verse used in creating Chava: ויבן ד' אלוקים את הצלע, which Chazal explain that it refers to Hashem braiding her hair. It does not seem to be a reason for why it is considered "building" but a proof that it is called "building".

Comment: Look at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17513/why-is-braiding-hair-building

Comment: @mmc99 Saw it, commented on it. Hoping to find better answers

Comment: @mmc99 Did I go about this wrong? I worded the question in a more specific way.

Comment: @mmc99 I found the explanation given by Rav Kook to be on the aggadic side, using the halacha as a spring board for his comments on beauty and and women.

Comment: @Moses613 I'm not sure whether this question is a duplicate. You can help make clear if it isn't if you [edit] the question to explain why this question is different (the focus on halacha), and why the answers there are insufficient. A comment on another post is not enough for that. [From review](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/close/29368).

Comment: @Shokhet I should reference the other question directly? I think the question is self evident that it is different.

Comment: @Moses613 I don't see how the question is different. That question does not ask for aggadic answers. It ask for all answers, so it also wants halakhic ones. This is clearly a duplicate. If you want better answers there, consider offering a bounty https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @DoubleAA The other question is not a question in hilchot shabbat but on the meaning of the word ויבן and how it refers to braiding.  Also, he is asking about a gemara in Nida, I am about a gemara in Shabbat. Clearly, it is not a duplicate. I wish this question got more attention then just "it is a duplicate".

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2146) might help:

> The Shulhan Aruch (Orah Haim 303:26; listen to audio recording for precise citation) rules that it is
>   forbidden for a woman to braid her hair, or to undo
>   a braid, on Shabbat. The Mishna Berura
>   (commentary by Rav Yisrael Meir Kagan, 1839-1933)
>   explains (listen to audio recording for precise
>   citation) that braiding hair is forbidden on Shabbat by force of Rabbinic enactment, and not on the level of Torah law.

Comment: Looking for an explanation for why this is so. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: If you look on that page I quote 
"The reason why the Sages forbade braiding hair on
Shabbat, the Mishna Berura explains, is because
braiding hair resembles building. Indeed, the Torah
relates that God “built” the rib taken
 from Adam into a woman, and Hazal interpreted this
 to mean that He braided Hava’s hair before bringing
 her to Adam. The Sages further noted that in certain
regions, the same word is used for “building” and
“braiding” “Binita”. In light of this association
between braiding and building, the Sages enacted a
prohibition against braiding hair on Shabbat.

Comment: Also I recall seeing (I don't remember where offhand I'll try to find it) being that a braid is usually made in a way that's meant to last its considered building

Comment: @mmc99 I have a hard to accepting that Chazal forbade something just because an association was made by words. See my edited question. I don't think that was the intent of the gemara. Although if you find a source for dailyhalacha's explanation that would be different.